# Como alterar um objeto em uma lista

Tags: java, array, lista, arraylist

Tenho uma classe com:

Nome;
Pin;
SaldoDaConta;

Quero fazer uma mudança no saldo da conta com base no pin.

Ex:

Input:Digite seu pin
Nome:Fulano
Saldo:xxxx

Digite o quanto que deseja retirar:R$
Você retirou: xx.x

Percorrer a Arraylist e com base no pin(ou nome) da conta fazer a alteração no dinheiro.

ex:tirar uma quantia

Obs: Sou iniciante e não entendi muito bem como funciona a Arraylist

Comment: Poste o código para que todos vejam e possam tbm executar e ajudar.

Comment: **>>>** https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8496/checklist-de-perguntas-do-stack-overflow?cb=1 **<<<**

Answer (score -1):

Existem métodos embutidos no Objeto de ArrayList que retornarão os objetos e assim você pode modifica-los.

A principio, você deve se perguntar qual a posição deste objeto no seu ArrayList, e se existe encapsulamento dos atributos deste objeto (Caso haja, é preciso os métodos Getters e Setters).

Vamos ao codigo:

Aqui eu crio o ArrayList entitulado listaPessoas e adiciono os objetos Pessoa nesta lista.
Obs: Este println é didatico, apenas para visualizar o objeto antes de qualquer alteração.

```
       // Criação do Arraylist
        ArrayList<Pessoa> listaPessoas = new ArrayList<>();
        
        //Criação dos objetos pessoa
        Pessoa pessoa1 = new Pessoa("Pedro", 20);
        Pessoa pessoa2 = new Pessoa("Erick", 30);
        
        System.out.println(pessoa1);
        System.out.println(pessoa2);
        
        
        // Adicionando pessoas na lista através do método add
        listaPessoas.add(pessoa1);
        listaPessoas.add(pessoa2);
```

Alterando o objeto Pessoa sabendo a posição do mesmo. Note que o método get já existe no Objeto ArrayList, ele recebe como parametro um número inteiro e retorna o objeto desta posição, como eu já sei qual a posição do meu objeto, eu posso altera-lo diretamente.

```
 // Alterando pessoa1 sabendo a posição da pessoa.
        System.out.println("#### Alterando Pessoa 1 ####");
        listaPessoas.get(0).nome = "Mickey Mouse";
        System.out.println(pessoa1);
```

Neste método, por não saber a posição da Pessoa 2, eu primeiro peço que a lista me retorne a posição referente ao objeto: método .indexOf(Objeto); Ele irá me retorna um número inteiro da posição daquele objeto no Array e assim irei utilizar o método get de cima.

```
System.out.println("#### Alterando Pessoa 2 ####");
        int indicePessoa = listaPessoas.indexOf(pessoa2);
        listaPessoas.get(indicePessoa).nome = "Donald";
        System.out.println(pessoa2);
```

Answer (score -2):

ArrayList é como um List (ou um vetor), mas de tamanho variável. Você não precisa percorrer o ArrayList, usa o **set()**. Você vai precisar importar **java. util**.
Pra fazer a mudança a partir do pin você precisa criar um método para isso.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).